# Filter cells in excel based on true value and not on formatted value

Tags: excel, formatting, filtering

I have this spreadsheet where in column A I have multiple categorical values, for sake of simplicity let's say it looks something like A/A/A/B/B/C/C/C/C.

Now, I would like to insert a line for the total after each group. Column A should end up looking something like this A/A/A/A TOTAL/B/B/B TOTAL/C/C/C/C/C TOTAL. Got this?

Problem is when I filter for, say, C values the "C TOTAL" does not show up together with the others. Now that seems right as the value "C TOTAL" is not the same as "C".

So I figured I could write "C" instead of "C TOTAL" and then apply a format like @ " TOTAL".
Now the value in the cell is the same as the others (i.e. "C") but *it shows* as if it was "C TOTAL".

I thought this would work, but still when I filter I see both "C" and "C TOTAL" listed.
Why does excel separate them if the value is the same? How can I do so that filtering only accounts for the *true* value in the cells and not their format too?

Thank you guys for your help!

Comment: What version of Excel are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Well I have a solution to your overall goal (not this specific problem, but it makes this problem unnecessary)

If you have a range (and NOT what I call a "Big-T Table" (Big-T Tables get the "Table Tools" context ribbon group to appear when selected)) then this solution could work for your goal of a total for each category.

Click in your data range -> Data Tab -> Subtotal (in outline group) -> select "at each change in" (probably your category) -> select your function of choice from dropdown -> Choose which columns to subtotal with checkboxes - > choose your other options -> done!

Here is example dialog box

[image]

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. +1 because it's something I didn't know and I find it quite interesting. Gonna play with it later. I'm not going to mark it as the correct answer though, as for my particular problem this solution is not 100% viable.

Comment: thanks. @Bruder Which portion isn't viable? I would like to add on a second possible solution that is viable for you if I can come up with one.

Comment: it's mostly because of aesthetic reasons. This stuff is supposed to be part of a report that has to adhere to some very strict (and yes, pointless) company specifics. The line with the total should show as A TOTAL when filtered. With your method, when I filter, all I see is the Grand Total line. I know it's silly but that's how (unfortunately for me) it is :)

Comment: Ah, that is unfortunate. I will try to see if i can come up with something (no guarantees I will succeed)